# how to define same entity configuration/validation in the whole solution in clean architecture

Tags: .net-core, clean-architecture

In the Infrastructure layer using entity framework, it's possible to define the entity configuration via IEntityTypeConfiguration.

For example, referring to a TodoList entity

**TodoListConfiguration**

```
public class TodoListConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TodoList>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TodoList> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(t => t.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(200)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

It set the table column *Title* property  *length* to 200 characters (nvarchar(200)) and the *allow null* to false.
This means that we need to create a validation that follows these constrain.
This is done by two validators in the application layer (I'm using cqrs pattern)

**CreateTodoListCommandValidator**

```
public class CreateTodoListCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateTodoListCommand>
{
    public CreateTodoListCommandValidator(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Title)
            .NotEmpty()
            .MaximumLength(200)
    }
}
```

**UpdateTodoListCommandValidator**

```
public class UpdateTodoListCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateTodoListCommand>
{
    public UpdateTodoListCommandValidator(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Title)
            .NotEmpty()
            .MaximumLength(200);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the behavior is specified multiple times and the code is duplicated 3 times

1. TodoList entity framework configuration
2. TodoList create validator
3. TodoList update validator

The problem increase according to the validation needed.

Has anyone figured out how to solve this issue?

(I'm referring to the https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture repo)

Comment: Duplication is not always evil. If create and update rules could change for different reasons, then it makes sense to have them in different classes. Otherwise you could validate a TodoListCommand and have create and update inherit from it. EF configs purpose is database schema configuration, which is yet another different reason to change. https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction

Answer (score 0):

Having the same piece of logic (validation in your case) showing up multiple times in your application means you have a specification.

[Here](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/ddd-bulk-operations), for example, you can learn how to implement the Specification pattern.